# Deduce parameter pack from default argument

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

Is it possible for the compiler to deduce a parameter pack from a function's default aargument? Particularly, I have the following code:

```cpp
template <int ... Is> struct seq {};
template <int ... Is> struct make_seq;
template <int head, int ... tail>
struct make_seq<head, tail...>
{
    using type = typename make_seq<head - 1, head - 1, tail...>::type;
};
template <int ... Is>
struct make_seq<0, Is...>
{
    using type = seq<Is...>;
};
template <int N>
using make_seq_t = typename make_seq<N>::type;

template<int N, int ...Is>
int deduceParamPack(seq<Is...> s = make_seq_t<N>{})
{
    return sizeof...(Is);
}

int main()
{
    return deduceParamPack<5>();
}
```

And the compiler deduces the parameter pack as empty, and tries to cast the default argument to it. Instead, I would like to achieve a similar behaviour to:

```cpp
int main()
{
    return deduceParamPack<5>(make_seq_t<5>{});
}
```

where the deduced parameter pack is `0,1,2,3,4`, without explicitly passing in this argument.

Comment: Instead of a default argument, you could have two overloads of `deduceParamPack`, one with a parameter and one without. The latter will call the former with an appropriate default.

Comment: "Is it possible for the compiler to deduce a parameter pack from a function's default aargument?" - no, as far I know.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was actually trying to avoid writing an additional helper function - that's how I got there in the first place. The former was a result of the impossibility of templating lambdas in c++17.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but be aware that you are reinventing [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and `std::make_integer_sequence`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The issue was that I could not see the definition of `std::make_integer_sequence` in msvc (it uses something like `__make_integer_seq<integer_sequence, _Ty, _Size>;`), but I supposed I should be using it anyways. As far as templated lambdas go, it seems like the preview msvc version + language standard set to latest allows those, so I can use this to create a helper lambda function inside my other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for the compiler to deduce a parameter pack from a function's default aargument?

No, as far I know.

But... not exactly what you asked... but maybe you can find useful the following solution based in partial specialization of structs

```
template <std::size_t N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N*N>>
struct deduceParamPackStruct;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct deduceParamPackStruct<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   static constexpr std::size_t func ()
    { return sizeof...(Is); }
 };
```

You can use it as follows

```
static_assert( 25 == deduceParamPackStruct<5>::func() );
```